# GetDate() giving Eastern time instead of Pacific Time

Tags: sql-server, datetime

SQL server 2016

```
SELECT GETDATE() AS myTime
```

> ```
> result: myTime: 2019-11-10 10:43: 15.873
> ```

I think this is US Eastern Time, however, I'm living in the West, how can I change this to US Pacific time. I want result `2019-11-10 7:43: 15.873`

thank you for all answers, I tried to find Time Duration between Now and the past, that why I try to use GetDate() to get current date/time my setup like this:

```
Declare @past_time datetime = '2019-11-09 8:40' 
Declare @current_time datetime 

set @current_time = GetDate() at time zone 'Pacific Standard Time';

select @current_time - @past_time;
```

The answer I got still having 3 hours extra, I know the fact that SQL server is on the east coast and i'm on the west coast.

Answer (score 2):

`GETDATE ()` basically gets the current system date-time, you probably got to check the server/system time zone where SQL server service is running that your querying to.

And you could convert into any zone as follows:

```
Declare @Datetime datetime = '2019-11-10 10:43';

select (@Datetime at time zone 'Pacific Standard Time')
```

For all time zone info

```
select * from sys.time_zone_info;
```

Comment: Good, do not forgot to check (green check mark) to the answer that works in your scenario. Hope you have been [through it..](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Anyway, welcome on-board!